# How to use solr to index json

Tags: solr4

I want to know can we index json into solr and if yes can we search the document on basis of key or value of json.

For eg:

**Can we index**

```
[
  {
    "id": "chapter1",
    "title" : "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
    "content_type": "chapter",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "1-1",
        "content_type": "page",
        "text": "ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1-2",
        "content_type": "page",
        "text": "more text... this is page 2 of chapter 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have indexed custom Jsons and the answer to your question is 'Yes', We can index Json into Solr using Admin UI or CLI. 
We can do Search query in solr, and search is performed on 'values'.